# Javascript SideBar Problems after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have a problem that will make me crazy, I've got a page that has a SideBar on the left that folds down. This sidebar, works very well when no ajax is called.
The problem occurs when an Ajax is called.
To be clearer the problem occurs with the `require_once('../include/js/js.php');`.

If I remove this part of the codes of the different ajax calls, the problem disappears, but I need this require once so that the array generated in the ajax is returned with the buttons provided by "DataTables.net" ( print button, copy....)

I thought I had solved the problem by removing the `require_once('../include/js/js.php');` on my Ajax files, but in fact not because it removes the buttons I need .

From what I see, the require once doesn't work as I would like...
I searched for 5 hours trying everything, but I think I lack the knowledge to solve this problem...

I will show you my full code :

Main Page :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["connection"]) && ($_SESSION["role"] >= 0)){
require_once("../../include/js/ShowNotif.php");
$title_page = "Historique d'un NameSpace - Beluga";
require_once("../../include/head.php");

?>
  <!-- Main content -->
  <div class="main-content" id="panel">
    <!-- Topnav -->
    <?php
    require_once("../../include/navbar.php");
    ?>
    <!-- Header -->
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header bg-primary pb-6">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="header-body">
          <div class="row align-items-center py-4">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-7">
              <h6 class="h2 text-white d-inline-block mb-0">Consultation</h6>
              <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="d-none d-md-inline-block ml-md-4">
                <ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-links breadcrumb-dark">
                  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
                  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="historyofnamespace.php">NameSpace</a></li>
                  <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Liste</li>
                </ol>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Page content -->
    <div class="container-fluid mt--6">
      <!-- Table -->
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card-wrapper">
            <!-- Input groups -->
            <div class="card">
              <!-- Card header -->
              <div class="card-header bg-Default">
                <h3 class="mb-0" style="color:white;">Historique d'un NameSpace</h3>
              </div>
              <!-- Card body -->
              <div class="card-body bg-Default">

                  <!-- Input groups with icon -->

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 mr-auto ml-auto">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-collection"></i></span>
                          </div>
                          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Code SA" type="text" name="codesa" onkeyup="checkForEnterKey(this.value);" id="codesa" value="">
                        </div> -->
                        <label for="codesa" style="color:white;">CodeSA</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codesa" name="codesa" placeholder="Saisir le code applicatif" aria-label="Saisir le code applicatif" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                          <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" id="clicksubmitsa" onclick="SubmitSA('SearchHistoryOfNamespace();');">Valider</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div id="resultatlistsa"></div>
                  <!-- Input groups with icon -->


              </div>



<div id="resultatlistofhistory"></div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>






      </div>
      <!-- Footer -->
      <?php
      require_once("../../include/footer.php");
      ?>



    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Argon Scripts -->
  <!-- Core -->


  <?php
  require_once("../../include/js/js.php");
  require_once("../../include/js/historydeploymentofnamespacejs.php");
  ?>

</body>

</html>

<?php
}else{
  header('Location: ../../connect.php');
} ?>
```

First Ajax call :

```
<?php
require_once('../include/php/AllFunction.php');
require_once('../include/js/js.php');
$codesa = strtolower($_POST['codesa']);
$fonction = $_POST['fonction'];
// SearchServicesOfANamespace(); SearchHistoryOfNamespace();

if(isset($codesa) && !empty($codesa)){
    $bearer = "";
    $Link = $ApiBaseLink."allhistorydeploymentnamespace";
    $object = GetHTTPRequest($Link, $bearer);

    if ($object != FALSE){
        $NombreSA = sizeof($object);
        ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 mr-auto ml-auto">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="namespace" style="color:white;">NameSpaces</label>
                <select id="namespace" name="namespace" data-toggle="select" class="form-control" onchange="<?php echo $fonction; ?>">
                  <!-- ShowLoadingProcess(); -->
                    <option selected disabled>Liste des namespaces</option>

                    <script>
                    var table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable();
                    table.destroy();
                    </script>

        <?php
                        for($SA = 0; $SA < $NombreSA; $SA++){
                          $namespace = $object[$SA]["namespacename"];

                          if (strpos($namespace, $codesa) !== false) {

        ?>
                            <option value="<?= $namespace; ?>"><?= $namespace; ?></option>
        <?php

      }
                        }
        ?>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }else{
      return http_response_code(404);
    }
}
?>
```

After the selection, latest ajax call :

```
<?php
require_once('../include/php/AllFunction.php');
require_once('../include/js/js.php');
$bearer = "";
$namespace = strtolower($_POST['namespace']);
?>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card bg-Default">
      <!-- Card header -->
      <div class="card-header bg-Default">
        <h3 class="mb-0" style="color:white;">Liste des services</h3>
        <p class="text-sm mb-0" style="color:white;">
          Voici l'ensemble de l'historique pour ce NameSpace.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-responsive py-4">
        <table class="table bg-white" id="datatable-buttons" data-turbolinks="false">
          <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th>NameSpace</th>
              <th>Composant</th>
              <th>Tag</th>
              <th>Date déploiement</th>
              <th>Date Création du Tag</th>
              <th>Par</th>
              <th>Date ajout composant</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th>NameSpace</th>
              <th>Composant</th>
              <th>Tag</th>
              <th>Date déploiement</th>
              <th>Date Création du Tag</th>
              <th>Par</th>
              <th>Date ajout composant</th>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody>
          <?php
          if(!empty($namespace)){

             $Link = $ApiBaseLink."historydeployment/".$namespace;
             $object = GetHTTPRequest($Link, $bearer);
             if($object != FALSE){
               $NombreHistoriques = sizeof($object);
               if ($NombreHistoriques > 0){
                    for($historique = 0; $historique < $NombreHistoriques; $historique++){
                      $id = $object[$historique]["id"];
                      $servicename = $object[$historique]["servicename"];
                      $tagversion = $object[$historique]["tagversion"];
                      $datedeploiement = $object[$historique]["datedeploiement"];
                      $datecreationtag = $object[$historique]["datecreationtag"];
                      $actionby = $object[$historique]["actionby"];
                      $dateajout = $object[$historique]["dateajout"];

                            ?>
                            <tr>
                              <td><span><?= $namespace ?></span></td>
                              <td><span><?= $servicename ?></span></td>
                              <td><span><?= $tagversion ?></span></td>
                              <td><span><?= $datedeploiement ?></span></td>
                              <td><span><?= $datecreationtag ?></span></td>
                              <td><span><?= $actionby ?></span></td>
                              <td><span><?= $dateajout ?></span></td>
                            </tr>
                          <?php

                  }
                }
              }else{
                ?>
                <script>
                ShowMessageNotification('error', 'Aïe ! L\'API n\'a pas répondu... ', 4000, 'top-end');
                </script>
                <?php
              }
          }else{
            ?>
            <script>
            ShowMessageNotification('error', 'Aïe ! Le NameSpace est vide... ', 4000, 'top-end');
            </script>
            <?php
          }
          ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JS.PHP file :

```
<script src="../../assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/js-cookie/js.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/jquery.scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/jquery-scroll-lock/dist/jquery-scrollLock.min.js"></script>
<!-- Optional JS -->
<script src="../../assets/vendor/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/datatables.net-buttons-bs4/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/datatables.net-select/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/datatables.net-buttons/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/datatables.net-buttons/js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/datatables.net-buttons/js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/vendor/chart.js/dist/Chart.extension.js"></script>
<!-- Argon JS -->
<script src="../../assets/js/argon.js?v=1.2.0"></script>
```

Just after loading the first Ajax, the SideBar is no longer straightenable, it freezes.
It remains stuck after the second AJAX.

The problem come from this :

```
VM8230:2655 Uncaught TypeError: $this.select2 is not a function
    at init (<anonymous>:2655:9)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:2667:4)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at <anonymous>:2666:11
    at <anonymous>:2671:3
    at b (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.dataFilter (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jquery.min.js:2
```

But my jquery is loaded only one time
I hope someone with experience can solve this problem, it makes me crazy really.. i don't understand why a require_once can cause this..

Comment: It's a process of elimination within the `js.php` file. Comment the lines one by one to find the problem. Once you know which file(s) are causing the problem, begin debugging further. We can't help solve this until you are able to provide a specific issue.

Comment: It is a problem to include js file many times ( i include js.php in each ajax because i need it ) so it's included too to the main right ? But the main know that it has already loaded the content , so it does not reload again right ?

Comment: You only need to include it once on each page that depends on those scripts.

Comment: Ok so i'm doing right.That's a shit problem :(

Comment: @EternalHour I updated my first post, i think this is my problem :  `VM8230:2655 Uncaught TypeError: $this.select2 is not a function
    at init (<anonymous>:2655:9)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:2667:4)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at <anonymous>:2666:11
    at <anonymous>:2671:3
    at b (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.dataFilter (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jquery.min.js:2`

But i load the jquery only once so i don't understand

Comment: `$this.select2` is nowhere in your question.